# ADFORM + GA4 - statistics differences

Tags: debugging, google-analytics, static-analysis, event-tracking, google-floodlight

I have a problem where my stats between Adform RTB plafotm and new GA4 disappear. Differences (depending on the day) oscillate in between the range of 40-50%. I'm trying to locate the source of the problem and I wanted to ask if any of you had a similar problem maybe and if you managed to solve it somehowe.

Thanks. :)

We checked the correctness of the code and flooflights in the LP containers and whether and when the request script is initiated. Additionally. We alsoconsulted with our reseller of google services.